# Pthread heap buffer overflow

Tags: c, memory, pthreads, buffer, overflow

I tried to create a multithread server using pthread. The compiling failed and gave a heap buffer overflow error.

I tried to change the buffer size, change the malloc size, etc., but got no luck. The code compiles successfully when the multithread part is removed. So I doubt this could be issues related within the thread memory allocation or free. Any ideas?

The warning looks like this

```
==6056==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000018 at pc 0x5603ede50e8a bp 0x7fffc737ded0 sp 0x7fffc737dec0
WRITE of size 8 at 0x602000000018 thread T0
```

Here is the server code.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "gfserver-student.h"

#define BUFSIZE 256
#define USAGE                                                                 \
    "usage:\n"                                                                \
    "  gfserver_main [options]\n"                                             \
    "options:\n"                                                              \
    "  -t [nthreads]       Number of threads (Default: 21)\n"                 \
    "  -p [listen_port]    Listen port (Default: 10823)\n"                    \
    "  -m [content_file]   Content file mapping keys to content files\n"      \
    "  -d [delay]          Delay in content_get, default 0, range 0-5000000 " \
    "(microseconds)\n "                                                       \
    "  -h                  Show this help message.\n"

/* OPTIONS DESCRIPTOR ====================================================== */
static struct option gLongOptions[] = {
    {"content", required_argument, NULL, 'm'},
    {"delay", required_argument, NULL, 'd'},
    {"nthreads", required_argument, NULL, 't'},
    {"port", required_argument, NULL, 'p'},
    {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}};

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t cond_worker = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
steque_t *queue;
pthread_t *workers;

typedef struct enque_ctx{
    gfcontext_t *ctx;
    const char *filepath;
}enque_ctx;

extern unsigned long int content_delay;

extern gfh_error_t gfs_handler(gfcontext_t **ctx, const char *path, void *arg);
extern ssize_t process_perform(gfcontext_t *ctx, const char *path);

static void _sig_handler(int signo)
{
    if ((SIGINT == signo) || (SIGTERM == signo))
    {
        exit(signo);
    }
}

// thread process function
void queue_init(gfcontext_t *ctx, const char *filepath){
    enque_ctx *q_ctx = malloc(sizeof(enque_ctx));
    q_ctx->ctx = ctx;
    q_ctx->filepath = filepath;
    steque_enqueue(queue, q_ctx);
}

void *process(){
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        while(steque_isempty(queue)){
            pthread_cond_wait(&cond_worker, &mutex);
        }
        enque_ctx *q_ctx = steque_pop(queue);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        process_perform(q_ctx->ctx, q_ctx->filepath);

        if(q_ctx->ctx != NULL){
            gfs_abort(&q_ctx->ctx);
        }
        // free(q_ctx->filepath);
        free(q_ctx);
    }
}

/* Main ========================================================= */
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int option_char = 0;
    unsigned short port = 10823;
    char *content_map = "content.txt";
    gfserver_t *gfs = NULL;
    int nthreads = 12;

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);

    if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGINT, _sig_handler))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't catch SIGINT...exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGTERM, _sig_handler))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't catch SIGTERM...exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Parse and set command line arguments
    while ((option_char = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:t:rhm:d:", gLongOptions,
                                      NULL)) != -1)
    {
        switch (option_char)
        {
        case 't': // nthreads
            nthreads = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'h': // help
            fprintf(stdout, "%s", USAGE);
            exit(0);
            break;
        case 'p': // listen-port
            port = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", USAGE);
            exit(1);
        case 'm': // file-path
            content_map = optarg;
            break;
        case 'd': // delay
            content_delay = (unsigned long int)atoi(optarg);
            break;
        }
    }

    /* not useful, but it ensures the initial code builds without warnings */
    if (nthreads < 1)
    {
        nthreads = 1;
    }

    if (content_delay > 5000000)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Content delay must be less than 5000000 (microseconds)\n");
        exit(__LINE__);
    }

    content_init(content_map);

    /* Initialize thread management */
    queue = malloc(sizeof(steque_t));
    steque_init(queue);
    workers = malloc(nthreads * sizeof(pthread_t));
    

    /*Initializing server*/
    gfs = gfserver_create();

    /*Setting options*/
    gfserver_set_port(&gfs, port);
    gfserver_set_maxpending(&gfs, 86);
    gfserver_set_handler(&gfs, gfs_handler);
    gfserver_set_handlerarg(&gfs, NULL); // doesn't have to be NULL!



    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        if (pthread_create(&workers[i], NULL, process, NULL) != 0) {
            printf("failed to create worker %d\n", i);
            return -1;
        }
    }

   
    /*Loops forever*/
    gfserver_serve(&gfs);

    for (int i = 0; i < nthreads; i++) {
        if (pthread_join(workers[i], NULL) < 0){        
            printf("failed to join pthread\n");
        }
    }

    steque_destroy(queue);
    free(queue);
    free(workers);
    free(gfs);
    content_destroy();
}
```

This is the handler code.

```
#include "gfserver-student.h"
#include "gfserver.h"
#include "content.h"

#include "workload.h"
#include "gf-student.h"

#define BUFSIZE 64000

extern void queue_init(gfcontext_t *ctx, const char *file_path);
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t cond_worker;

//
//  The purpose of this function is to handle a get request
//
//  The ctx is a pointer to the "context" operation and it contains connection state
//  The path is the path being retrieved
//  The arg allows the registration of context that is passed into this routine.
//  Note: you don't need to use arg. The test code uses it in some cases, but
//        not in others.
//
gfh_error_t gfs_handler(gfcontext_t **ctx, const char *path, void* arg){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    queue_init(*ctx, path);
    pthread_cond_signal(&cond_worker);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    return gfh_failure;
}

ssize_t process_perform(gfcontext_t *ctx, const char *path){
    char buff[BUFSIZE];
    size_t filelen, size_transferred = 0;
    ssize_t recv_len, send_len;
    int flides;
    if((flides = content_get(path)) < 0){
        return gfs_sendheader(&ctx, GF_FILE_NOT_FOUND, 0);
    }
    printf("%d\n", flides);
    filelen = lseek(flides, 0, SEEK_END);
    gfs_sendheader(&ctx, GF_OK, filelen);

    while(size_transferred < filelen){
        recv_len = pread(flides, buff, BUFSIZE, size_transferred);
        if(recv_len <= 0){
            printf("Handle receive error\n");
            gfs_abort(&ctx);
            return -1;
        }
        send_len = gfs_send(&ctx, buff, recv_len);
        if(send_len != recv_len){
            printf("Handle send error\n");
            gfs_abort(&ctx);
            return -1;
        }
        size_transferred += send_len;
    }
    return size_transferred;
}
```

Original main function template

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "gfserver-student.h"

#define USAGE                                                               \
  "usage:\n"                                                                \
  "  gfserver_main [options]\n"                                             \
  "options:\n"                                                              \
  "  -t [nthreads]       Number of threads (Default: 21)\n"                 \
  "  -p [listen_port]    Listen port (Default: 10823)\n"                    \
  "  -m [content_file]   Content file mapping keys to content files\n"      \
  "  -d [delay]          Delay in content_get, default 0, range 0-5000000 " \
  "(microseconds)\n "                                                       \
  "  -h                  Show this help message.\n"

/* OPTIONS DESCRIPTOR ====================================================== */
static struct option gLongOptions[] = {
    {"content", required_argument, NULL, 'm'},
    {"delay", required_argument, NULL, 'd'},
    {"nthreads", required_argument, NULL, 't'},
    {"port", required_argument, NULL, 'p'},
    {"help", no_argument, NULL, 'h'},
    {NULL, 0, NULL, 0}};

extern unsigned long int content_delay;

extern gfh_error_t gfs_handler(gfcontext_t **ctx, const char *path, void *arg);

static void _sig_handler(int signo) {
  if ((SIGINT == signo) || (SIGTERM == signo)) {
    exit(signo);
  }
}

/* Main ========================================================= */
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int option_char = 0;
  unsigned short port = 10823;
  char *content_map = "content.txt";
  gfserver_t *gfs = NULL;
  int nthreads = 12;

  setbuf(stdout, NULL);

  if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGINT, _sig_handler)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't catch SIGINT...exiting.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  if (SIG_ERR == signal(SIGTERM, _sig_handler)) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Can't catch SIGTERM...exiting.\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  // Parse and set command line arguments
  while ((option_char = getopt_long(argc, argv, "p:t:rhm:d:", gLongOptions,
                                    NULL)) != -1) {
    switch (option_char) {
      case 't':  // nthreads
        nthreads = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      case 'h':  // help
        fprintf(stdout, "%s", USAGE);
        exit(0);
        break;
      case 'p':  // listen-port
        port = atoi(optarg);
        break;
      default:
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", USAGE);
        exit(1);
      case 'm':  // file-path
        content_map = optarg;
        break;
      case 'd':  // delay
        content_delay = (unsigned long int)atoi(optarg);
        break;
    }
  }

  /* not useful, but it ensures the initial code builds without warnings */
  if (nthreads < 1) {
    nthreads = 1;
  }

  if (content_delay > 5000000) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Content delay must be less than 5000000 (microseconds)\n");
    exit(__LINE__);
  }

  content_init(content_map);

  /* Initialize thread management */

  /*Initializing server*/
  gfs = gfserver_create();

  /*Setting options*/
  gfserver_set_port(&gfs, port);
  gfserver_set_maxpending(&gfs, 86);
  gfserver_set_handler(&gfs, gfs_handler);
  gfserver_set_handlerarg(&gfs, NULL);  // doesn't have to be NULL!

  /*Loops forever*/
  gfserver_serve(&gfs);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is almost certainly wrong:

```
enque_ctx *q_ctx = malloc(sizeof(q_ctx));
```

`sizeof q_ctx` is the size of a pointer, since that's what `q_ctx` is; you need to allocate enough memory to contain `*q_ctx`, which I suppose is larger than a single pointer.

Comment: Thank you! I just corrected it. Still the same error...

Comment: Who owns the memory for the filepath string passed to `gfs_handler`? The fact that the parameter is `const` suggests that it is owned by the caller; if so, you need to make a copy (and later on free the copy). Memory ownership is an important aspect of asynchronous programming; I hope it has been covered in your class. If not, ask your professor.

Answer (score 0):

In `main` ...

You define:

```
gfserver_t *gfs = NULL;
```

Later on, you do:

```
gfs = gfserver_create();
```

But, then you do (e.g.):

```
gfserver_set_port(&gfs, port);
```

This is incorrect.

You are passing the equivalent of a "double star" pointer (e.g.)

```
gfserver_t **
```

To a function that *only* takes a regular pointer (e.g.)

```
gfserver_t *
```

I'm surprised that this even compiles.

What you really want is (e.g.):

```
gfserver_set_port(gfs, port);
```

There are other calls that have similar issues.

---

> Actually gfserver_set_port takes a double pointer as input, So I don't think the problem is here `void gfserver_set_port(gfserver_t **gfs, unsigned short port);` –
> user2236600

Taking a double pointer for such a control struct is *very* unusual. I know of very few APIs that would take that approach.

I had done a web search prior to posting to verify the prototypes. The only match I came up with is: https://github.com/stewartboyd119/ud923-project1-gflib/blob/master/gfserver.h

It uses regular, single pointers for the four functions that your `main` code is calling.

So, I'm confused. The library/API you're using must be different, but it's not publicly available AFAICT.

Comment: Thank you. I notice this issue. However this is the prewritten code template provided for me as it's a course project. I noticed there are some interchange use of double and single pointer. The original main function is provided

Comment: Actually gfserver_set_port takes a double pointer as input, So I don't think the problem is here ```void gfserver_set_port(gfserver_t **gfs, unsigned short port);```